# The index 1 is out of range (SQL Server Exception)

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm getting index 1 is out of range error, but it works when I

> String sq ="Select*from Credentials where username=admin and password=admin";

to

> String sq ="Select*from Credentials where username=? and password=?";

I have a SQL Server database where the "admin" stored in row number 6.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=FYP;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    String sql ="Select*from Credentials where username=? and password=?";
    String sq ="Select*from Credentials where username=admin and password=admin";

    PreparedStatement pst2=con.prepareStatement(sq);
    pst2.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());
    pst2.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());
    ResultSet rs2= pst2.executeQuery();

    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());
    pst.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs2.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password Matched");
        NewJFrame l = new NewJFrame();
        l.setVisible(true);
        l.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        super.dispose();
        //setVisible(false);

     } else if(rs.next()){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password Matched");
         MainPage l = new MainPage();
         l.setVisible(true);
         l.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         super.dispose();
         //setVisible(false);

     } else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password not Correct");
         txtUsername.setText("");
         txtPassword.setText("");
     }

     con.close();

} catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: The query text for `sq` contains no parameters, so you can't use `setString()`. Additionally: string values need to be enclosed in single quotes, so the query should be `where username = 'admin' and password = 'admin'` - but using a query like that is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: What is the alternate way of doing this? without using setString().

Comment: You *should* be using parameterized SQL - just use your `sql` variable rather than `sq`, and set the parameter values to "admin". (I would note that having passwords in plaintext like this is very, very insecure by the way...)